Wildcard `Match` not working for fluentbit config using absolute file paths in tags
We have a FluentBit agent running on our EKS cluster using the tail input for some logs.
[INPUT]
    Name                tail
    Tag                 kube.*
    Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
    DB                  /var/log/containers/log.db
    multiline.parser    cri
    Skip_Long_Lines     Off
    Refresh_Interval    10
    Mem_Buf_Limit       200MB

I'm needing to map some fields to be more compliant with the Elastic Common Schema since we're outputting our logs to Elastic. We have a problem error field that is a string when it needs to be in the format error: { message: <value> } instead. So I have these filters:
# Fix aws-load-balancer-controller logs which output `error` as a string
[FILTER]
    Name                modify
    Match               kube./var/log/containers/aws-load-balancer-controller-*
    Rename              error error_message
[FILTER]
    Name                nest
    Match               kube./var/log/containers/aws-load-balancer-controller-*
    Operation           nest
    Wildcard            error_message
    Nest_under          error
    Remove_prefix       error_

I have confirmed that the files being processed are at that file path, but I don't see these transformations being applied.
What am I doing wrong?

I found the answer for myself and thought I'd share. The tail input docs in Fluentbit says:

Note that "tag expansion" is supported: if the tag includes an asterisk (*), that asterisk will be replaced with the absolute path of the monitored file

What they do not say, at least not in the docs for tail is that the absolute path of the monitored file has its / characters replaced with . characters. You have to follow the referenced Kubernetes doc to find this side note:

note that slashes are replaced with dots.

With that knowledge, the Match can be replaced:
# Fix aws-load-balancer-controller logs which output `error` as a string
[FILTER]
    Name                modify
    Match               kube.var.log.containers.aws-load-balancer-controller-*
    Rename              error error_message
[FILTER]
    Name                nest
    Match               kube.var.log.containers.aws-load-balancer-controller-*
    Operation           nest
    Wildcard            error_message
    Nest_under          error
    Remove_prefix       error_

